# Replace primary key Identity with sequence starting with next AUTO_INCREMENT value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I currently have a table, `Messages`. The `ID` column is the primary key and is populated using an Identity.

```
x-----------------------------x
|    ID       |  Contents     | 
x-------------|---------------x
|    1        |  01234        |
|    2        |  56789        |
x-----------------------------x
```

I want to remove the identity on the `ID` column and replace it by populating the default value of `ID` from a sequence, `Messages_ID_Sequence`.

This is easy enough to accomplish in SSDT. However, when I deploy the database project, the first value in `Messages_ID_Sequence` is 1. It's obvious why when I look at the SQL generated for `Messages_ID_Sequence`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[CommandMsgs_MSGID_Sequence]
    AS BIGINT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO CYCLE
    CACHE 10
```

The problem happens when I try to insert a new Message record. The first value from the sequence, 1, populates the ID column of the new record and causes a violation of the primary key constraint.

So how can I ensure that when `Messages_ID_Sequence` is created, it starts at the next `ID` that the identity would have provided? The Build Action on `Messages_ID_Sequence`'s creation script must be set to Build so the solution can't involve anything that SSDT doesn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct dinamically the SQL sentence to create your sequence, so it starts at your last identity.

```
/* Read the last identity value */
DECLARE @value bigint;
select @value = max(id_field) from my_table;

/* Create the sequence starting at that value */
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[CommandMsgs_MSGID_Sequence] AS BIGINT START WITH ' + cast(@value as nvarchar(20)) + ' INCREMENT BY 1 NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE CACHE 10;';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

Or update at any moment your sequence so it starts at the desired value.

```
/* Read the last identity value */
DECLARE @value bigint;
select @value = max(id_field) from my_table;

/* Create the sequence starting at that value */
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'ALTER SEQUENCE StreamEntrySequence RESTART WITH ' + cast(@value as nvarchar(20)) + ';';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

Comment: When would I execute this? As a post-deployment script? If it's added into my post-deployment scripts it will execute every time I publish the database. It doesn't look like that would necessarily be harmful but it's wasteful given that it only needs to be done once per environment.

Comment: You can execute it on your deployment script, just after the creation of the sequence.

Comment: I have updated the answer so now it directly creates the sequence, so you only need to call it once when you update your database.

Comment: The sequence is generated by SSDT and the creation script I posted has Build Action set to Build. I cannot replace the creation script with the script in your answer as it causes the following error: SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.

Comment: Ok, then I'm sorry but I don't know of another solution than restart your sequence on a post-deployment script as in the first answer I posted. As you said, it's harmless to do so but wasteful because only the first execution is really necessary. I have posted both approaches on the proposal.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll leave the question open for a few days to see if anyone comes up with anything we haven't thought of. If not, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.